# Stacking Dynamic Text Fields Flash/ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, textfield

I am adding a series of text fields through a loop based on an XML file. The width of the fields is always going to be `200 px` so depending on how much text is contained in the XML node, the height of the text field will vary. I need a way to stack these fields on top of each other based on their height plus say a `10 px` space between each. Below is how I am creating the text fields.

```
for(var i:int; i < xml.item.length(); i++)
{
    var theText:TextField = new TextField();
    addChild(theText);
    theText.wordWrap = true;
    theText.width = 200;
    theText.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
    theText.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    theText.selectable = false;
    theText.htmlText = xml.item[i].@theText;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep track of the height by using the height of the text field.

```
var startHeight:int = 0;
for(var i:int; i < xml.item.length(); i++)
{
    var theText:TextField = new TextField();
    addChild(theText);

    theText.y = startHeight;

    theText.wordWrap = true;
    theText.width = 200;
    theText.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
    theText.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    theText.selectable = false;
    theText.htmlText = xml.item[i].@theText;

    startHeight += theText.height + 10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something simple. Only one small change for anyone else who comes across this, the first line should be: "var startHeight:int = 0;"

Comment: Haha yeah editing that too much C++/AS3 mixing does that sometimes :)